# Sinatra can't serve JavaScript files without help? Is this correct?

Tags: ruby, model-view-controller, sinatra

Ok, so I'm not having trouble with this per say, but I want to make sure that I'm doing this right because it just seems like a lot of extra work in the long run.

I am working with Sinatra and using HAML templates. I want to include a JavaScript file from my HAML file. My directory structure looks like this:

- media/

  - js/

    - init.js **(file I want to include)**
  - css/
- models/
- views/

  - layout.haml
- routes/
- init.rb
- bootstrap.rb **(included in init.rb)**

When I try to include the file (with no extra routes or anything) I get a page cannot be found error. However, if I add this code, then it works fine:

```
get '/media/js/:name' do
    begin
        send_file('media/js/' + params[:name])
    rescue
       "There's nothing for you here"
    end
end
```

I have no problem doing this for serving my media/static files, but I just want to make sure that this is necessary, I would like to avoid this is possible.

**EDIT**

I included the following code to my bootstrap.rb file, but to no avail:

```
set :root, File.dirname(__FILE__)
enable :static
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [Sinatra's Website](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro):

> Static files are served from the ./public directory. You can
>   specify a different location by setting the :public option:
>
> ```
> set :public, File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/static'
> ```

You are serving from the `media` directory.

Comment: ok, I'm still getting a page cannot be found error when I used the following code `set :public, File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/media'` in my `bootsrap.rb` file

Comment: assuming you are going to `localhost:4567/media/js/foo.js`: when you set public, that directory is assumed to be the root dir of the server. So, instead of `localhost:4567/media/js/foo.js`, use `localhost:4567/js/foo.js`

Comment: Or instead, create a folder called public and move `media` into that folder.